# Converting Epoch to SQL server Date and checking whether its older than 12 months

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table with the Epoch values. I have to delete the records which are older than 12 months .. so maybe for that I have to convert the epoch values into datetime and check whether they are older than 12 months or not. Can you please help on this to write a TSQL script.

I can check the records which are older than 12 month by writing a where clause `column_name < dateadd(month,-12,getdate())` but how to check with the epoch values?

Thanks for you help!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, Epoch time is the number of seconds passed since January 1st 1970 (not including leap seconds, but that's totally negligible - 27 leap seconds between 1972 and 2016 [according to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second)).
Assuming you are keeping these values in an int column, You can simply convert the date of one year ago to Epoch time and remove all the records where the value of that column is smaller than the value you get.
To get Epoch time from the current datetime simply use `DATEDIFF`:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND, '1970-01-01T00:00:00', GETUTCDATE())
```

Easy enough to add to this `DATEADD` to get the date 12 months ago:

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF(
            SECOND, 
            '1970-01-01T00:00:00', 
            DATEADD(
                YEAR,
                -1,
                GETUTCDATE()
            )
        )
```

So I would go with something like this:

```
DELETE 
FROM TableName
WHERE EpochColumn <= DATEDIFF(
                        SECOND, 
                        '1970-01-01T00:00:00', 
                        DATEADD(
                            YEAR,
                            -1,
                            GETUTCDATE()
                        )
                     )
```

Please note that by converting the date value to Epoch instead of the other way around, you are also allowing SQL Server to use any indexes you might have on that column, meaning better performance.